# Active IDs in date ranges

Tags: oracle, date, range

I have requirement to get number of customers active in a month based on their revenue contribution period.

**Original Data:**

```
ACCOUNT_ID  REVENUE_START_DATE       REVENUE_END_DATE
1234         1/14/2010 0:00          4/13/2010 23:59
4567         2/9/2010 0:00           3/8/2010 23:59
1234         5/9/2010 0:00           6/8/2010 23:59
```

**Expected Result**

```
Month   Count
Dec-09  0
Jan-10  1
Feb-10  2
Mar-10  2
Apr-10  1
May-10  1
Jun-10  1
Jul-10  0
Aug-10  0
Sep-10  
Oct-10
```

Below is the oracle code I worked on (with help of google) but I am not getting correct result due to overlapping dates.  I request the experts to help me with this.  (Thanks in Advance)

**Current Result:**

```
YEAR_   MONTH_  ACT
2010    January     2
2010    February    3
2010    March       3
2010    April       3
```

**ORACLE CODE:**

```
with tab as
(
     select distinct ACCOUNT_ID,  billing_start_date as revenue_start_date, billing_end_date as revenue_end_date
     from accounts
                ),                    
     year_tab as 
                (
                    select 
                             add_months(min_date, level -1) m
                    from 
                            (
                            select min(trunc(revenue_start_date,'YYYY')) min_date, add_months(max(trunc(revenue_end_date,'YYYY')), 12) max_date
                            from tab
                            )
                    connect by level <= months_between(max_date, min_date)
              )     
select to_char(m,'YYYY') year_,
         to_char(m,'Month') month_,
         nvl(act, 0) act
from   year_tab,
            (            
            select m date_,count(*)  act
            from tab, year_tab
            where m between trunc(revenue_start_date,'MM') and trunc(revenue_end_date,'MM')
            group by m
            ) month_tab
where m = date_(+)
order by m;
```

Comment: I get your expected results (apart from it shows all the months in 2010, rather than Dec-2009 to Oct-2010). I'm not quite sure what the question is... are you sure your sample data is what you're actually using (not least since the column names are using your `tab` aliases).

Comment: Hi Alex.. Thank you for reviewing the code.  The issue I find here is that during the month of January 10, revenue is generated only by Account ID "1234" but the result of this query shows 2 and similary, for the month of Feb, revenue is generated by Account Ids '1234" and "4567" but the query shows 3.  I am exactly not sure of the reason.. Could you please help me? ..

Comment: But when I create an `accounts` table with your three rows of data, your query gives me `1,2,2,1,1,1` as expected. Something is missing from this picture...

Comment: May be I am missing something that i am not able to explain.  Please download the spreadsheet from the below link where I have given my orignal data and the results.   https://citrix.sharefile.com/d-sd5a1f9ef4f54fbd8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's taken me a while to see why you think there is a problem. With the original three rows of data you supplied, running your query gives exactly your 'expected result'. With the 54 rows of data from your CSV file, the result is 48 rows (covering four years), with non-zero totals from January 2010 to January 2013. The first few rows returned are:

```
YEAR_ MONTH_                                      ACT
----- ------------------------------------ ----------
2010  January                                       2 
2010  February                                      3 
2010  March                                         3 
2010  April                                         3
2010  May                                           2
```

But that looks correct:

```
select * from accounts
where not (billing_start_date > date '2010-02-01'
        or billing_end_date < date '2010-01-01');

ACCOUNT_ID BILLING_START_DATE BILLING_END_DATE 
---------- ------------------ ------------------
      1234 09/01/2010 00:00   08/02/2010 23:59   
      4567 14/01/2010 00:00   13/04/2010 23:59   

 2 rows selected 

select * from accounts
where not (billing_start_date > date '2010-03-01'
        or billing_end_date < date '2010-02-01');

ACCOUNT_ID BILLING_START_DATE BILLING_END_DATE 
---------- ------------------ ------------------
      1234 09/01/2010 00:00   08/02/2010 23:59   
      4567 14/01/2010 00:00   13/04/2010 23:59   
      1234 09/02/2010 00:00   08/03/2010 23:59   

 3 rows selected 

select * from accounts
where not (billing_start_date > date '2010-04-01'
        or billing_end_date < date '2010-03-01');

ACCOUNT_ID BILLING_START_DATE BILLING_END_DATE 
---------- ------------------ ------------------
      4567 14/01/2010 00:00   13/04/2010 23:59   
      1234 09/02/2010 00:00   08/03/2010 23:59   
      1234 09/03/2010 00:00   08/04/2010 23:59   

 3 rows selected
```

But what I think you wanted wasn't really stressed in the question: 'to get **number of customers** active'. Assuming that by 'customer' you mean unique account IDs, you just need to modify the count:

```
    select m date_,count(distinct account_id)  act
    from tab, year_tab
    ...
```

... which gives the first few rows as:

```
YEAR_ MONTH_                                      ACT
----- ------------------------------------ ----------
2010  January                                       2 
2010  February                                      2 
2010  March                                         2 
2010  April                                         2 
2010  May                                           1
```

What you were doing wrong was trying to apply the `distinct` in your `tab` subquery; but distinct returns distinct rows, and as the dates were different that wasn't actually reducing the number of rows returned.

Which doesn't quite match your expected result still, but does seem to match the data (if my assumption about what you want is right), and still does give your expected result for you three-row sample.

---

Another way to write the query, which I find a bit easier to follow, and using ANSI join syntax:

```
with t as (
    select add_months(min_date, level - 1) month_start,
        add_months(min_date, level) next_month_start
    from (
        select trunc(min(billing_start_date),'YYYY') min_date,
            add_months(trunc(max(billing_start_date),'YYYY'), 12) max_date
        from accounts
    )
    connect by level <= months_between(max_date, min_date)
)
select to_char(t.month_start,'YYYY') year_,
    to_char(t.month_start,'Month') month_,
    count(distinct a.account_id) act
from t
left join accounts a on not (billing_start_date > t.next_month_start
    or billing_end_date < t.month_start)
group by t.month_start
order by t.month_start;
```